# Hashing and Salting passwords with shiro

Tags: java, hash, salt, shiro

In apache shiro the default hash implementation is as follows:

```
MessageDigest digest = getDigest(getAlgorithmName());
        if (salt != null) {
            digest.reset();
            digest.update(salt);
        }
        byte[] hashed = digest.digest(bytes);
        int iterations = hashIterations - 1; //already hashed once above
        //iterate remaining number:
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            digest.reset();
            hashed = digest.digest(hashed);
        }
        return hashed;
```

Notice how it puts the salt first.  We are having to authenticate against a legacy system where the hashes were password + salt and not salt+password

I'm currently doing the concat outside this method call and passing null in for the salt. Aside from subclassing and overriding this method is there a better way than what I'm having to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out subclassing SimpleHash and overriding one method did the trick. Just reset the digest, add the salt then the pw and then digest it and it works fine